# How to create a simple gallery that diplays images when hovering and clicking text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently updating a website and I'm looking for a relatively easy way to create a product display.

I would like to have the same layout as **Example 1** which has 3 columns—2 on the left containing text links and 1 on the right where the images are displayed after the click.

- **Example 1**: http://imagethrow.com/design-studio-all-throws.html

  *this site currently uses iFrame tags which I don't want.

I also want it to display the images on hover *(see **Example 2** .floatRight sample)*

- **Example 2**: http://alt-web.com/DEMOS/CSS-Disjointed-Rollover-3.shtml#

  *the issue with this is that it uses span tags which I don't want. 
  Also, when you click on a lower link—***link item 8*** for example, and then hover over the above links, the above links aren't visible (looks like a stacking issue or something).

If this is posible with html/css that would be great! if not, I'm sure a little bit of javascript/jquery won't hurt me.

I've been looking for a solution to this all week, so any help or a point in the right direction would be very apprciated.

Comment: i think the click and the hover would conflict. What would be the point of clicking when the image is already there because you hovered over it?

Comment: I'm basing the hover and click option after Example 2. On that example, when you hover over a link the image appears, but when you move the mouse outside of the example box the image disappears. However, when you click a link and move the mouse outside the box the image stays. I guess i'd like the option to have the image stay when the mouse is moved outside of the box. I'm not sure how jQuery handles this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you lay out your columns and your links in html. Then use jQuery for the image swap. May not be a good idea for the hover, especially if you have the same lay out as you have found in example one unless you use hover intent. But this is how you would do it.

1. You will need to have [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/download)
2. This will need to be loaded before your script for the image swapping

The HTML for the link and img tag where you will put your image

```
 <a class="imgLink" href="path-to-the-image.jpg">Image name</a>
 <img src="" id="theImage">
```

the script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.imgLink').click(function(){
            var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#theImage').attr('src',imgPath);
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This worked great! thank you very much @realseanp... just a slight syntax error with the second from last closing tag. I remedied it below.

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.imgLink').click(function(){
            var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#theImage').attr('src',imgPath);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>`